# RabbitMQ distributing messages unevenly to consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

We're seeing an issue where consumers of our message queues are picking up messages from queues at the top of the alphabetical range. We have two applications: a *producer*, and a *subscriber*. We're using *RabbitMQ 3.6.1*.

Let's say that the message queues are setup like so:

[image: Fig A]

Our first application, the *producer*, puts say 100 messages/second onto each queue:

[image: Fig B]

Our second application, the *subscriber*, has five unique consumer methods that can deal with messages on each respective queue. Each method binds to it's respective queue. A *subscriber* has a prefetch of 1 meaning it can only hold one message at a time, regardless of queue. We may run numerous instances of the *subscriber* like so:

[image: Fig C]

So the situation is thus: each queue is receiving 100 msg/sec, and we have four instances of *subscriber* consuming these messages, so each queue has four consumers. Let's say that the consumer methods can deal with 25 msg/sec each.

What happens is that instead of all the queues being consumed equally, the alphabetically higher queues instead get priority. It's seems as though when the *subscriber* becomes ready, *RabbitMQ* looks down the list of queues that this particular ready channel is bound to, and picks the first queue with pending messages.

In our situation, A_QUEUE will have every message consumed. B_QUEUE may have some consumed in certain race conditions, but C_QUEUE/D_QUEUE and especially E_QUEUE will rarely get touched.

If we turn off the *publisher*, the queues will eventually drain, top to bottom.

**Is it possible to configure either *RabbitMQ* itself or possibly even the channel to use some sort of round robin distribution policy or maybe even random policy so that when a channel has numerous bound queues, all with messages pending, the distribution is even?**

Answer (score 2):

to clarify: you have a single subscriber application with multiple consumers in it, right?

I'm guessing you're using a single RabbitMQ Connection within the subscriber app.

Are you also re-using a single RabbitMQ Channel for all of your consumers? If so, that would be a problem. Be sure to use a new Channel for each consumer you start.

Comment: We only wish to have one thread per subscriber application, so that means multiple consumers on a single channel as prefetch is per channel.

Comment: To elaborate on this: each application is single threaded, and we only want one message to be processed at a single time. So a single channel with a prefetch of 1 fixes this.

Comment: "multiple consumers on a single channel" - then i don't think you're going to solve the problem you have

Comment: I thought as much. It wasn't a problem up until recently. Thanks anyway, appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the picture is wrong, but if it's not then your setup is wrong. You don't need 4 queues if you are going to have subscribers that listen to each and every queue. You'd just need one queue, that has multiple instances of the same subscriber consuming from it.

Now to answer, yes (but no need to configure, as long as prefetch is 1), actually rabbitmq does distribute messages evenly. You can find about about that [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html), and on the same place actually how your setup should look like. Here is a quote from the link.

> RabbitMQ just dispatches a message when the message enters the queue.
>   It doesn't look at the number of unacknowledged messages for a
>   consumer. It just blindly dispatches every n-th message to the n-th
>   consumer.

Comment: unless the exchange is duplicating messages (using fanout) because he want's every message to be processed at least 5 times, yeah, I think he has overcomplicated things.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback both. When we were designing the system, we had two choices: queue per type, which gives us metrics and fine-grained control, or one big queue where we encapsulate the object. We went with the former in the end. I don't think RMQ distributes unevenly, it's just that with prefetch of one, the "next message" is always in the top queue.

Comment: You can do queue per type, that's fine and even better, but you also need to have a "subscriber per type" in that case. The RMQ queues are FIFO. And the distribution goes in the "first came first served" principle, so the first connected subscriber gets the first msg etc... I'd appreciate feedback if the question is answered or not? It is about configuring round-robin distribution, but I might have missed something?

Comment: I totally get that RMQ queues are FIFO, but if you take a simpler example: four queues each with 100 messages on. Take a subscriber with one channel but four binds, one to each queue, and prefetch 1. The subscriber would each through the first 100 messages of the first queue before moving onto another. Why the "first" queue? Because it's alphabetically higher? Is there a way to randomise that rather than pick the alphabetically highest queue? That's the question, and I don't think it's answered per se.

Comment: Just to point out, the actual implementation is a lot more complex than this, but this is the simple version I've boiled it down to. So it may make you think "oh well why do it that way" but there are reasons that we have it set up this way, we just need a more uniform distribution rather than first queue in the array with pending messages.

Comment: Hope that makes sense!

Comment: A bit :) But I'm afraid that you are missing the point. Once again, there is no need for a subscriber to bind and consume from multiple queues. Unless it's a multithreaded and each tread has a channel and binds to a queue and consumes it. Which are actually then multiple "logical consumers" inside of one process.

Comment: there's not enough information in this post or comment section to judge whether or not the setup is wrong. it doesn't matter, either. it's Adam's project and setup; his constraints and requirements

Comment: @DerickBailey Ok the setup may be a bit to much to say, but one logical subscriber consuming from more queues, possibly over the same channel, that can't be good. EDIT: I see now your answer as well, you already mentioned the channel issue :)

Comment: Aye, the actual project is much bigger than the example I've provided, and maybe some of the details I cut out would have given you a better understanding, but it's a bit too late for the team to swap out how we're doing it now.

Comment: Everything works perfectly, except for the fact that there is no way to make RabbitMQ dish out multiple binds on a single channel (normal function btw) in any way other than first-come-first-serve. Which is understandable, I was just wondering if perhaps RabbitMQ had this functionality. Appreciate the responses though!